# Understanding function

Tags: javascript, math

I am having trouble understanding a function hopefully someone can help me out here. I am trying to find the pitch diameter of a sprocket the function for this in JavaScript is:

```
function sprocket_diam(dataform,pitch,teeth)
{



   var a,b,c,d,e;

   a = pitch / 2;
   b = teeth * 2;
   c = 360 / b;
   d =  Math.sin ((c * Math.PI) / 180);
   e = (a / d) * 2



    dataform.diam.value = e;

}
```

The above function works just as intended but I am trying to do this by hand on a calculator. I think the problem I am having comes in the `d` variable. For example lets say I have a `15` tooth sprocket with a pitch of `.5"`. Using the above formula the numbers for the variables I get are:
`a=0.25`,`b=30`,`c=12`, and for `d` I take `(12*3.14)/180` which gives me `0.2093` so `e=(0.25/.2093)*2` which ends up being `2.388915432` but is the incorrect answer it should be `2.404867172372066` Can someone point out what I am doing wrong? I have always struggled with math.

Comment: are you sure pitch & teeth are doubles?

Comment: @user1737909 What do you mean ?

Comment: In your hand calculations, it should be `e = (0.25 / Math.sin(.2093)) * 2`, not `e = (0.25 / .2093) * 2`. With that change, the error from using 3.14 instead of `Math.PI` yields 2.4060690729394008 (instead of 2.404867172372066).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't compute the sinus. (Math.sin)

Comment: +1. This accounts for most of the discrepancy. The rest is from using 3.14 instead of the more accurate `Math.PI`.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that you do as if `Math.PI` would be `3.14`.

If you use the precise value of `Math.PI`, you get `12*Math.PI/180 == 0.20943951023931953` instead of the `0.2093` you use and at the end you find `2.404867172372066`

Comment: I tried your example and got the `0.20943951023931953` but it will give me `2.3873241463784302557385799320236` as the answer

Comment: What gives you `2.3873241463784302557385799320236` ? There's no way you get that with the code you have.

Comment: OP isn't getting 2.387... from the code. It's from hand simulation of the code. The hand simulation left out taking the sine.